# GameMaker: saving highscore

Tags: android, game-maker, gml

I am having trouble getting my app to save high-scores when I am testing it on an android device; It seems to work fine on the windows simulator. I've made a save script and a load script, is there something I am missing?

(Using GML code)

In the save script i have:

```
ini_open("global.highscore.ini");
ini_write_real("global.score","global.highscore",score);
ini_close();
```

In End Game event:

```
ini_open("global.highscore.ini");
global.highscore = ini_read_real("global.score","global.highscore",score);
ini_close()
```

Comment: Please add in code snippet and also what language you're using for us to be of assistance! Remember, we're not mind reader or people that can hack into your device and see your screen!

Comment: sorry about that, let me know if what i added is not enough

Comment: It should be good enough, thanks! Sadly, I don't know GML and it took late for me to do some research to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just testing the game by connecting your computer to your Android device, export the .APK file to your computer first. Next, take the file, place it in a folder on your Android, and install it manually.

Comment: Kindly use comments for clarification instead!

Comment: Oops, I see what you all mean about answers versus comments; my apologies! I will be sure to correctly respond in the appropriate place next time.